# Oracle DBLink issue (ORA-02020)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I am struggling to understand why I keep getting the **ORA-02020: too many database links in use** error, but only at some locations.  Background: I have an Oracle 11g server at corporate that talks to Oracle 11g servers in 30 different locations.  I run the following SQL statements in sequence talking to each location:

```
INSERT INTO rx_net
SELECT  rxtx.dispensed_drug_ndc,
        d.drug_name,
        txtp.balance_due_from_tp
        TRUNC (rxtx.reportable_sales_date) "DISPENSE_DATE",
        TRUNC (rxtx.will_call_picked_up_date) "SOLD_DATE",
        TRUNC (rxtx.return_to_stock_date) "CANCEL_DATE",
        (dc1.cost_amount / d.pack) * rxtx.fill_quantity "ACQ_COST",
        txtp.final_copay,
        rxtx.fill_quantity "FILL_QTY",
        txtp.balance_due_from_tp + txtp.final_copay "TOTAL_PRICE",
        pt.bin_number,
        rxtx.uc_price,
        rx.rx_number,
        LPAD (SUBSTR (ss.VALUE, 1, 3), 3, 0) "STORE_NUM",
        rxtx.partial_fill_status "PARTIAL_FILL",
        pt.pcn,
        card.group_code,
        pl.carrier_code,
        (dc2.cost_amount / d.pack) * rxtx.fill_quantity "AWP"
FROM schema.rx_summary@store01 rx, 
    schema.rx_tx@store01 rxtx, 
    schema.tx_tp@store01 txtp,
    schema.drug@store01 d, 
    schema.drug_cost_type@store01 dct1, 
    schema.drug_costs@store01 dc1,
    schema.store_registration@store01 sr,
    schema.patient_tp_link@store01  ptl,
    schema.card@store01             card,
    schema.plan@store01             pl,
    schema.plan_transmit@store01    pt,
    schema.store_settings@store01   ss,
    schema.drug_cost_type@store01   dct2,
    schema.drug_costs@store01       dc2
WHERE rx.id = rxtx.rx_summary_id
    AND rxtx.id = txtp.rx_tx_id
    AND rxtx.dispensed_drug_ndc = d.ndc
    AND d.id = dc1.drug_id
    AND dct1.id = dc1.drug_cost_type_id
    AND ptl.id = txtp.patient_tp_link_id
    AND card.id = ptl.card_id
    AND pl.id = card.plan_id
    AND pl.id = pt.plan_id
    AND d.id = dc2.drug_id
    AND dct2.id = dc2.drug_cost_type_id
    AND dct1.cost_type = 'ACQ'
    AND dct2.cost_type = 'AWP'
    AND rxtx.will_call_picked_up_date BETWEEN '01-APR-17' AND '08-APR-17'
    AND rxtx.nhin_store_id = sr.nhin_store_id
    AND ss.name = 'storeDescription.storeNumber'
    AND txtp.counter = 0
    AND pt.site_code = 'ERX1'
ORDER BY rxtx.reportable_sales_date;

commit;
alter session close database link store01;
```

The SQL will execute (either in Toad or on the server in SQLPlus) fine for the first seven locations, but when it hits location 8 if fails with that error.  I've had this happen on other SQL, either for all locations, or other 'breakpoint' locations. I've always just worked around it, but decided that now is the time to resolve the problem.

Today I decided to execute the SQL and run the command `select * from v$dblink;` after every "alter session..." statement, but before location 8 it shows "no rows selected," so it seems it isn't a delay between "alter session" and the dblink being shutdown.  While the SQL is running, I will see 4 open sessions to a single location, so it makes me wonder if recursive calls to the same server is possibly the problem. I have also resisted changing the OPEN_LINKS setting greater than 4, because it feels like I'm masking the core problem.

Any ideas or wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which end of the link is throwing the error? And are any of the remote tables actually synonyms or views that are onward links to somewhere else?

Comment: The error is thrown by the "corporate" server rather than the remote server.  None of the tables are views, but I can't confirm if any of the tables are synonyms.  I will reach out to the software company that developed the system and get back to you.

Comment: Confirmed, no synonym's in use in the system. I started thinking about it, and it works in some stores and not in others, so wasn't sure that would have been the problem.